# Проверка условия при выполнении внешней команды

Tags: python

```
if (os.system(test['command'])):
    result='OK'
else:
    result='FAIL'
```

для примера, os.system выполняет такую команду:

```
uname | grep Linux
```

в таком случае os.system возвращает в оператор if найденую подстроку - Linux
и, вроде бы непустая строка == true, однако в этом примере всё наоборот отчего то
и вместо выполнения первого блока, выполняется блок else
если же вместо test['command'] поставить

```
uname | grep qwerty
```

то выполняется блок true, хоть и возвращается пустая строка
в чем дело?

Comment: А кто его знает. Только результат `os.system('uname | grep qwerty')`    у меня -- число 256. Возможно это exit status утилиты grep, возможно какие-то питоновские штучки, но никак не "лжа" в условном выражении.

Comment: а версия питона?
у меня в 2.7 возвращает или 0 или 1 только

Comment: Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вероятно, в вашей системе [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) возвращает [`exit status`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXITSTATUSREF). В posix системах считается, что команда завершилась успешно, если она вернула `exit status` равный `0` и с ошибкой, если статус отличный от нуля.

Что бы избежать проблем с различным поведением команды на разных системах, лучше пользоваться модуле [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), как и рекомендуется в документации.

```
if subprocess.call(["true"]) == 0:
    result = 'OK'
else:
    result = 'FAIL'
```

**UPD.**

Что бы подавить вывод, можно либо перенаправить stdout и stderr в /dev/null:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as nul:
    if subprocess.call(['echo', 'test'], stdout=nul, stderr=nul) == 0:
        result = 'OK'
    else:
        result = 'FAIL'
```

Либо воспользоваться функцией `subprocess.check_output`:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(['false'])
    result = 'OK'
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    result = 'FAIL'
```

Comment: пробовал как call() так и system(), в чем кстати разница?
что первый, что второй вариант выводит на экран результат, как этого избежать?

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ